# How can I preload this page with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can I preload all of the information on the page shown in the video below? The page only loads the first 20 applications and as you scroll it will load 20 more when you get to the bottom so 20, 40, 60, etc. Is there a way to use selenium to preload all of the applications? The page is using it's own scroll bar and not the browsers.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTVyNoQvdJs

Solved using this code

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
body = driver.find_element_by_class_name('selected_box')
body.click()
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="interview_list"]/div[4]/p/strong')
        break
    except:
        actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        actions.perform()
```

Comment: By "applications" do you mean the video suggestion thumbnails?

Comment: @LukeHamilton By applications I mean the blurred out squares. Each square is someone applying and includes details about their application, but the page only loads 20 of them at a time. By scrolling to the bottom it loads 20 more each time you get to the bottom.

Comment: Got it, then my answer should be sufficient. Keep me updated in how it goes!

Comment: @LukeHamilton Solved it using a combination of what you suggested and ActionChains, I added it to my question so you can see how I did it if interested! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Action chains is another way to go about doing it. Well done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in several different ways. In this example, I will be by using the the page down command in the keys function selenium library:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

---

Simply put this in a for loop for a specific number of attempts, or embed this within a while loop until desired XPATH is found.

### Example using for loop

```
body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
for i in range(X):
    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

### Example using while True loop

```
body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("DESIRED_XPATH")
        break
    except:
        body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```